# Coloring rows of mat-table in Angular 8 with different shades of a color (each row - a shade) based on the value of a numeric field (column)

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using mat-table, where
for each row I have two columns - 'Content' and 'Score'. The idea is to color all the rows in varying shades of same color according to their descending (or ascending) scores.

For instance something which would look like this-

[image]

I tried to add styling on the specific cell of the row where I want the shade to appear, by writing a method which based on 'Score' calculates some color.

HTML file (Score column)

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">

            <!-- Search_content Column -->

            <!-- Score Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="score">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="col3"> Score </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let i= index;" [style.background-color]="getB(element.score )"> {{element.score}}</td>
            </ng-container>           


            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let i = index;"></tr>
          </table>
```

And then in the Typescript file, I have a method that returns color code-

```
  getB(score: number): string {

    let normScore = score / this.topScore;

    let colorNum = 0;
    colorNum = normScore*100;
    let startStyle = 'hsl(35,40%,';
    let endStyle = '%)';



    let style = startStyle+ colorNum+ endStyle;
    //ex - hsl(35, 40%, 45%) 
    return style;


    }
```

This works fine.

However,I want to know- is there any Angular material functionality that already does this or any other simpler way of coloring the rows in varying shades, perhaps any CSS trick or some package that does this.

Thank You

Comment: One simpler simpler-way: `return \`hsl(35,40%, ${(score/this.topScore)*100}%\`` :)